# IV drip/flow rate controller design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, applied-mechanics, mechanisms, medical-devices

I have a question about intravenous flow rate controllers, which are controlled using microprocessors. For example: [image: iv-flow-controller]

I want to control the IV flow rate, the flow is in range from 0 to 300. So, I just put a number between 0 drips/minute to 300 drips/minute in a 10 scale from the computer interface, and the microprocessor would control the flow rate to the desired number. For example, when I put 60 drips/minute on the computer interface, the microprocessor controls the mechanism until the flow rate reaches 60 drips/minute. The tubing used by the IV dispenser is a form of PVC plastic.

I've been trying to use a pinching mechanism like in the picture below. I'm using that kind of mechanism because it is easier to insert and remove the tube from the device when required. But, the mechanism still doesn't give the precise output that is specified, also it is unstable.

[image: pinch]

So, how can the flow rate be controlled just by using motors such as a servo motor or a motor DC and microprocessor?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Our ["be nice" policy](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) is a basic requirement for participation. I'm getting pretty tired of deleting your comments so if you keep using them to vent your frustrations, I'll save us both some trouble and frustration by excusing you from the site.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: There's nothing wrong with critiquing a post on its technical merits (or lack thereof), but the role of "language lawyer" really does not suit you, especially given the errors that often appear in your own posts, and it's rubbing a lot of people the wrong way. If you don't want to read a post for any reason, then stop reading it and move on. There is no reason to leave a comment disparaging the poster's character. If the post truly has no merit, other reviewers will deal with it in due time.

Comment: rafifadl, welcome to Engineering SE. Please give us a little more detail about your situation. Are you trying to control the flow rate of a water-based solution through some tubing? Is this for an IV or is the IV only a similar example? Characteristics of the tubing and desired range of flow rates are important to know.

Comment: @Air Hi, i'm sorry if my post was bad, i've edited it. yes, i'm trying to control the flow rate of a water-based solution through some tubing. Yes, this is for an IV. the desired flow rate decided by user, from 0 to 300 in a 10 scale. the tubing is using medical grade PVC plastic tube

Comment: So what kind of mechanism do you think is in the commercial machine shown in your picture? It is likely a version of the plastic one that you have shown. It seems like you need to focus your question on what may be improved with your current mechanism.

Comment: @hazzey i think the commercial machine using hydraulic pump or something like that

Comment: what about adding a feedback mechanism?  something that constantly pinches/unpinches based on how many drops have passed in the last minute (or ten seconds, or some appropriate time)?

Comment: @user2539738 i already use feedback mechanism. but my problem is on the pinching system. i haven't found the right system.